# Intersección de polígonos geométricos 4623 en MySQL que regresa vacío

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas, una que contiene una columna con todos los poligonos geograficos con SRID (proyección 4623) de México Tabla: I.

Despues yo creo un poligono y lo guardo en otra tabla Tabla: G.

Lo que estoy intentando es que me regrese todos los registros de la tabla I que son intersectados por el poligono que tengo en la tabla G.

```
SELECT * FROM I as i JOIN G as g ON ST_INTERSECTION(g.g, i.GeomAGEB);
```